# Unsure of what siding to choose. Looking for advice

Tags: siding

We are making our first big home improvement investment due to significant siding rot and I’m really struggling with which route to go. Information about bids:

Company 1: Alside Ascend siding. Rip and replace all existing siding. No new gutters; siding only. 38k quote

Company 2: James Hardie siding. Rip and replace only rotting existing siding and lay over the rest. Includes new gutter system and downspout. 31k.

Am I missing something? Why is company 2 so much less than 1? My thought is rip and replace of everything is the smart way to go (plus i prefer the Ascend based on what I’ve read) but it’s also hard to ignore the $7k savings. Any advice is appreciated as this is a nerve-racking decision.

Comment: Only two quotes for plus 30k. Shame on you.  Does your location have any outside risks?  Hail, wildfire, floods.  Can your house use better insulation/air sealing?  Any labour you can do yourself(ripping siding off) will help the price.

Comment: I know . Yes, hail for sure, potentially fire but that is a lower risk. Definitely need better insulation and sealing. The existing siding is ~40 year old T1-11

Comment: Many sidings out there.  You want hail proof, maybe burn proof as a bonus.  Adding insulation needs the inside or the outside removed(some blown in just requires small holes fix).  Insulation/sealing you can probably do yourself once the siding/sheeting is removed.  If you have the time, one wall at a time for insulation, till ready for siding.  Main tools needed is a hammer, a prybar, a stable gun.

Comment: TBH, I'm somewhat surprised that the "replace some" estimate is lower. It takes a lot of time & effort to successfully weave in new siding to old and make it look good. Does either include paining?

Comment: 2 Considerations: 
1. Depending on the condition of the Sheathing behind the Siding, you may want to have it replaced also (I replaced my rotten fiberboard with Zip wall Sheathing which made a Huge difference as it includes a water-resistive barrier)
2. Sprinkle Boric Acid inside the Sheathing. Unlike other bug killers, Boric Acid will work forever as long as it is kept dry and being between the sheathing and the Sheetrock is perfect. You'll never see another roach again, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain how contractors do estimates. It's mostly two strategies:

Strategy 1 is to just use the linear feet of the perimeter of the house times the number of floors and multiply that by a magic number, the "industry standard" or "going rate" or whatever number they decide to pull out of their sleeves. This allows the company to have a salesman that knows little about the installation processes but can answer lots of calls and crank out quick estimates to land many jobs. The obvious problem is that the labor costs depend on many factors other then linear feet, e.g. access (e.g. how easy to set up scaffold and deliver materials close to the house), number of windows, number of corners (ie a house that looks like a cube is a lot easier than a house with many additions over the years), etc. etc.

It's a good strategy as long as your magic number is high enough to average the easy and difficult jobs. In other words, the clients with easy jobs are overpaying, and the difficult jobs are underpaying.

Strategy #2 is to have an actual person who knows about the production process do estimates and consider all factors like access, number of windows and doors, number of corners, current conditions (needs strapping/furring?), need for improvements (Frieze board? Soffits?) etc. Then the estimator adds up the cost of materials, the labor costs, adds a multiplier for "general conditions", equipment depreciation, and a profit and ends up with an estimate.  This will take longer, increase expenses (it takes hours per house, and nobody pays for estimates), lands fewer jobs since they can't just hire salespeople, but the contractor makes money on every job. Clients with easy jobs hire this company because they get a lower price, clients with difficult jobs hire another company.

The different strategies is how you end up with an estimate for $10,000 vs. $50,000 for the same job. In my experience, a difference of 20% between estimates is not that unusual. Get a couple more estimates just to be sure.

Everything else being equal: reputation of the company, references, etc., you should be able to safely choose the cheaper price.